# NCurses wrefresh messes up terminal if in separate function

Tags: c++, ncurses

I've created the following class:

```cpp
class UIWin {
    WINDOW* win;
public:
    UIWin() {
        WINDOW* win = newwin(5, 6, 10, 10);
        refresh();
        wborder(win, '|', '|', '-', '-', '+', '+', '+', '+');
        wrefresh(win);
    }
    ~UIWin() {
        delwin(win);
    }
};
```

It works as one would expect, drawing a box on screen, if the following function is called:

```cpp
void testUI() {
    UIWin w;
    getch();
}
```

However, if I move the

```cpp
        wborder(win, '|', '|', '-', '-', '+', '+', '+', '+');
        wrefresh(win);
```

into its own method of UIWin, and call that right after initializing a UIWin in testUI like so:

```cpp
void testUI() {
    UIWin w;
    w.display(); // calls the wborder & wrefresh functions
    getch();
}
```

my terminal gets borked
[image: borked termianl]
and other commands' formatting is screwed with (ls, for example)
[image: borked ls command]

My main function:

```cpp
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    initscr();

    testUI();
    
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

---

I'm very confused

Comment: This has nothing to do with ncurses. You have two variables named `win`. One is a member of the class and one is a local variable in the constructor. They have nothing to do with one another. They just happen to have the same name. If you want to store the value returned by `newwin` in the `win` member of the class object, it should be `win = newwin(5, 6, 10, 10);`, not `WINDOW* win = newwin(5, 6, 10, 10);`. The latter syntax with a type is a declaration of a variable, not an assignment expression statement.